# Virtualizing Windows 7 on linux host for Windows Phone application development

Tags: linux, windows, windows-phone, virtualization

I was asked to delvelop a Windows Phone application but it turns out that Windows Phone SDK works only under Windows 7 OS. At work I only have a shitty old laptop running Windows XP with not enough resources to run a virtual machine. My solution to this problem was to install VMware Workstation on my Asus 1215B netbook (Ubuntu 12.04LTS) but Windows Phone emulator runs very slowly.

I was just curious if I would use different GNU/Linux host like Debian/Centos/Gentoo and more lightweight user enviroment like xfce there would be an inprovemant in performance.

I also considered writing a script which would ask a user if he wants to logon to the host shell or start a Virtual machine before loading host system enviroment and services.

Answer (score 0):

Just dual-boot windows 7 with Ubuntu on your laptop.. nothing can beat the performance on the bare metal... and making things minimalistic would naturally make the performance better... but probably not MUCH better.

Comment: I bought this machine w/o OS and I want it to stay that way ie. I refuse to install windows host on it. I was thinking about installing win7 or more likely different linux host just for tests on a usb 3.0 external drive though I'm still kinda afraid that using external drive would somehow influence the performace of the system.

Comment: Probably, it would be much much better than virtualization

Answer (score 0):

You could always setup a headless virtualbox environment, install Windows 7, and then connect to it via RDP.

The following is a guide that you could use to help you setup the virtual environment with a php management interface:

http://www.howtoforge.com/managing-a-headless-virtualbox-installation-with-phpvirtualbox-ubuntu-12.04

There are also guides to setting it up without the php interface on howtoforge.

Maybe another avenue for you to try, hope it helps.

Trevor

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to dual boot unless you have lots and lots of RAM since the WP emulator needs a few GB.